# How to pass Search Bar input as props to another screen in react navigation?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have a stack navigator where i have defined the searchScreen where i wish to get the input data and also have a SeachBar component which i attached in the stacknavigators headers as custom header.

**My question is, how can i get the typed input data from search component to SearchScreen?**

*StackNavigator.js*

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="SearchScreen"
    component={SearchScreen}
    options={{ headerTitle: (props) => <SearchBar {...props} /> }}
  />
```

*components/Searchbar.js*

```
import { Searchbar } from "react-native-paper";
<Searchbar
    placeholder="Search"
    onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
    value={searchQuery}
    loading="true"
    icon={() => <FontAwesome name="search" size={15} />}
    style={{
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 0,
      shadowColor: "transparent",
      borderBottomColor: "transparent",
      borderTopColor: "transparent",
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, use a global state  searchText in redux and use it anywhere you want.

Comment: Yes, that is a way. But i thought if there is any other way using react navigation itself. If not will have to use redux.

Comment: You can use context, if you don't want redux, and the app is not too big.